# What does this way of writing mean?

Tags: c#

This is probably a stupid question, but when I see code like this

```
var newList = list.OrderBy(x => x.Product.Name).toList();
```

I wonder that does the `(x => x.Product.Name)` mean?
Like, what is `x` and what does the `=>` mean?

I don't know what to search for in order to obtain more information on this subject, any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: (input parameters) => expression read this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Comment: you can search on `C# Lambda Expressions`

Comment: @Mike if you know that they're called that. You can also search for "C# equals greater than".

Comment: @CodeCaster, i liked that

Comment: Just to add, for searching programming terms like that, use http://symbolhound.com/ , I searched for `C# =>` and look at the [results](http://symbolhound.com/?q=C%23+%3D%3E)

Answer (score 0):

Look on google for Lambda Expression. Here is a link to the MS page for Lambda Expressions - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It's called a [Lambda Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

A lambda expression is a way of passing a method as a parameter. The lambda expression above could be written as a method, possibly like this:

```
public string GetProductName(Thing x)
{
     return x.Product.Name;
}
```

So we see that `x` is a parameter into the method, or lambda expression in this case.

The `OrderBy` method in LINQ then uses this "method", or lambda expression, to know how to sort the list - OrderBy itself knows nothing about your objects or how to sort them, so we pass in a lambda which order by invokes.

---

In the case of `IQueryable`, lambda expressions are not actually code that gets invoked, but rather an expression tree is built. A lambda can be used to satisfy a delegate, or it can be used to build an expression tree. This is a bit of a complex subject, but worth mentioning.